# How to Rename the SpagoBI server?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, business-intelligence

I am working on SpagoBI business intelligence.I have configured and created some reports and olap cubes successfully, but i want to change the server name SpagoBI to our custome name.How to change this?

I want change SpagoBI to CheliyanBI

I am trying this last 7 days but i couldn't do this.Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you ever done this task? i really need this

Answer (score 1):

if you are on tomcat and you are using SpagoBI 4.1 the following procedure should work:
- launch SpagoBI in the standard configuration
- connect to SpagoBI as administrator
- in the Configuration Management change the value of the SpagoBI Context variable to your new context
- shutdown SpagoBI
- change the value of the spagobi_service_url variable in the server.xml file
- change the value of the Path variable in the context.xml of SpagoBI webapp
- change the value of the display-name variable in the web.xml of SpagoBI webapp
- rename the SpagoBI folder as you prefer
- clean the work/Catalina/localhost and conf/Catalina/localhost
- start SpagoBI
Eventually clean the browser cache

Comment: Hi, when you say to change the value of spagobi_service_url you mean to add the context at the end of the url? like http://localhost:8080/newcontext/SpagoBi ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

open your server in IDE (microsoft visuaa studio , ....) and Rename *Spago* with Cheliyan
then Rename Main folders SpagoBI to CheliyanBI
SpagoBIAccessibilityEngine to CheliyanBIAccessibilityEngine
....

hope this work (it work for me)